# Limit results of one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables region(name, number), city(region_number, name, population), and I want to return the first 5 cities with highest population along with the region's name. This is my query, but it only returns the 5 cities of one region(North in this case) instead of all regions:

```
SELECT region.name AS region_name, city.name AS city_name, city.population AS population
FROM region INNER JOIN (SELECT city.name, city.population, city.region_code
FROM county  LIMIT 5) AS city
ON region.code = city.region_code;
```

Desired output:

```
     region_name |        city_name         | population 
------------+----------------------------+------------
 NORTH     | A                           |     226338
 NORTH     | B                           |      13656
 NORTH     | C                           |       9478
 NORTH     | D                           |       2464
 NORTH     | E                           |       2464
 WEST      | A                           |     226338
 WEST      | B                           |      13656
 WEST      | C                           |       9478
 WEST      | D                           |       2464
 WEST      | E                           |       2464
```

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, don't use `limit` without `order by`.  You are getting five arbitrary cities.

What you are trying to do is a bit of a pain in MySQL.  The following should work, though:

```
SELECT r.name AS region_name, c.name AS city_name, c.population AS population
FROM region r INNER JOIN 
     county c
     ON r.code = c.region_code
WHERE 5 >= (SELECT count(*)
            FROM county c2
            WHERE c2.region_code = c.region_code and c2.population >= c.population
           )
ORDER BY region, population DESC;
```

The `where` clause counts the number of cities with a population as big or bigger than the given city.  The only cities returned are those in the top 5.

Answer (score 2):

[LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) is your SQL keyword friend, use `SELECT ... ORDER BY population LIMIT 5`.